# Is it possible to import/download someone else's public Picasa album?

Tags: picasa-web-albums

Does Picasa or any tool download someone else's public album?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download public web albums but there are a couple of caveats:

- Although the album is public the owner of the album has to manually allow downloads of the album.

  - Settings > Privacy & Permissions > Allow any visitor to: > Check "Download my Photos"
- You can only only download albums using the Desktop application - it can't be done using the web version.